# Gmail API AccessToken is generating after selecting the Gmail account in browser and allow the permissons to access the api but we need directly

Tags: c#, oauth, google-api

I have used the Gmail API Oauth2.0 clientid and secret values to generate the accesstoken in c#.net console desktop application.after run the appliction it redirecting to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth....... to choose the gmail account after selecting that asking the permission to allow the access then generating the accesstoken after allow the access permission. please help me out to generate accesstoken without using redirect uri in c#.net
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/My0I6.png)

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you think the problem is. Why do you want to avoid the redirect? That's how oauth works. What issue is it causing you?

Comment: P.s. I'm assuming you followed the instructions as per https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app?